# Can I use a wireless surveillance cam as web cam and use it with Skype?

Tags: wireless-networking, skype, webcam

Can I use a wireless surveillance cam as web cam and use it with Skype?

[this is the cam I'm curious about, DCS-2121](http://www.dlink.co.uk/cs/Satellite?c=Product_C&childpagename=DLinkEurope-GB%2FDLProductCarousel&cid=1197375412134&p=1197318962342&packedargs=ParentPageID%3D1197318962321%26TopLevelPageProduct%3DConsumer%26locale%3D1195806691854%26packedargs%3DProductParentID%253D1195808623840&pagename=DLinkEurope-GB%2FDLWrapper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tend to say no.  Surveillance cams generally are network devices unto themselves - they usually setup as web servers and the camera posts pictures to its own website on the internal server.

Skype would normally require a camera setup as a device on your local machine.